# Creating a Managed C++ interface to use in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com, c++-cli, dcom

We have a collection of Native C++ business rules wrapped in C++/CLI and then by a C# layer so we can expose it via DCOM.

The Native C++ business rules are in a DLL and are easily invoked in C++/CLI which is in a COM visible DLL. We then add this DLL as a reference to the C# project.

The C# layer has a lot of classes derived from ServicedComponent and we apply regsvcs to get it registered as a DCOM server.

However a need has arisen for the C++/CLI layer to communicate to the C# layer. To do this I was thinking of using a C# style interface. The C# layer will derive from the interface and pass it down to the C++/CLI layer which can then call methods on it to get something to occur in the C# layer. This interface will need to be declared in the C++/CLI layer though for visibility. This is my problem I do not seem to be able to achieve this.

Is there a way to declare a C# style interface in C++/CLI and then use it in C#?

Comment: "Managed C++" refers to Visual C++ with Managed Extensions, as in Visual Studio .NET 2003. You probably mean its successor C++/CLI. If so, please reword and changed the tags.

Comment: Changed as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/737cydt1.aspx):

```
#pragma managed
using namespace System;

public interface class MyInterface
{
    void MyFunction();
}
```

And used in C#:

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    public void MyFunction() { }
}
```

Comment: If I declare it like that I get. error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyInterface' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: BTW The assembly and using statement are there. If I remove the method MyFunction from the class deriving off MyInterface I get Intellisense errors that "Interface member xxx is not implemented"

Comment: I edit the answer to show exactly what I've compiled without error. I'm using VS2013.

Comment: Okay but how is a C++/CLI Interface used in a C# assembly without error. I get errors for some reason.

Comment: You need a class to implement the interface.

Comment: Which is where I get the failure I mentioned above - your code sample shows an interface declaration only. Have you got the scenario I mention working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78485/discussion-between-david-gray-wright-and-jaket).

Comment: It looks like my Solution was referencing an old Assembly off the hard disk and not the appropriate project. I fixed it up and reopened the solution and now its working.

Comment: Had a bit of a struggle with this today, I only created a .h file in C++ (in which the interface was defined). This was never included anywhere in the C++ project so wasn't compiled. Problem solved by creating a cpp file which inculded the .h file. I guess if I'd written the code in the C++ project to use this interface, before testing it in C#, I wouldn't have had this problem!